# According to theories of embodiment, am I in all my body?

Tags: phenomenology, mind-body, merleau-ponty

According to theories of embodiment, am I in all my body? Am I in my fingernails and teeth, even when I do not feel them? If I pick up a large stick, then am I in the stick, when I poke things with it? What if it's strapped to my arms? What about prosthetic or bionic limbs, do I exist in them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how can i add clarity to what i asked?

Comment: See [Embodied cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embodied_cognition#History) and the reference to Merleau-Ponty: "Merleau-Ponty in his *Phenomenology of Perception* rejects the cartesian idea that people's primary mode of being in the world is thinking and proposes corporeity, that is, the body itself as the primary site for knowing the world. 'The body is the vehicle of being in the world, and having a body is, for a living creature, to be intervolved in a definite environment, to identify oneself with certain projects and be continually committed to them.' "

Comment: So, maybe yes: if "poking things with a stick" is part of your "knowing the world" (it seems a quite limited one, anyway)...

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as asking: In which sense is it meaningfull to say “I am in my body?”

1. Expressed in modern terms the question asks about the content and
   the limits of the human self-model. This topic is the focus of the
   Self-model theory from philosophy of mind, more specific from Thomas
   Metzinger’s theory [Being No One: The Self-Model Theory of
   Subjectivity](https://www.amazon.de/Being-No-One-Self-Model-Subjectivity/dp/0262633086).

   During the first phase of his life, when exploring his environment,
   the child learns to distinguish between what belongs to his body,
   what does not, and where is the boundary.
   A fundamental experience
   when touching his own body, e.g. touching his foot by his hand: The
   child gets **two** feedback stimuli, from the hand and from the foot.
   While when touching the things around him the child only gets **one**
   feedback, namely from the touching hand. Objects of the first type
   become components of the self-model, while those of the second type
   become components of the world model.

   Step by step ***all*** components of the self-model become classified as
   “my”: My foot, my hand, my body, my wishes, my thoughts,…, me!

   The concept of "I" is a construct within the self-model. It is the umbrella term for all its components. In so far one may say "I am in all of my body".
2. Ongoing experiences with the use of sticks or tools – also using protheses
   and bionics - may shift a bit the boundary between my body, as part of the self-model, and the
   rest of the world. Even nerves which no longer start from
   an existing limb – because the limb has been amputated - may send stimuli to the
   corresponding modules in the brain. The mind classifies these
   stimuli according to their point of arrival and processing. The
   neural stimulus is then interpreted as a feedback from the limb as
   before.
3. On the other hand, strong meditation may weaken the border of the
   self-model and dissolve the border between me and the outer world.
   This dissolution is expericenced as the so called *oceanic boundlessness*.

**Aside**: The last lines of your question “I am in my body The Phenomenology of Perception” seem to be a relic from an earlier version.

Comment: Hello Jo. Thank you for the reply, but you did not answer whether I am in all of my body, and so I am struggling to completely map what you say. It's useful to read someone's thoughts anyway

Comment: @user66698 I expanded my answer as requested.